# ¿Por qué en Colombia se llama "mona" a la mujer de pelo rubio?

Tags: etimología, adjetivos, colombia

Como español en Colombia, me sorprendió esta conversación más de una vez.

> —Sí, esa chica **mona**...
>   —Bueno, muy guapa no me parece.
>   —No, no dije eso sino que es mona.
>   —¿...?
>   —Sí, de pelo rubio.
>   —Aaaah.

Como intento reflejar en el ejemplo, para un español alguien [*mono*](http://dle.rae.es/?id=PeswonB%7CPevMcDo) es descrito por el DLE como *de aspecto agradable por cierto atractivo físico, por su gracia o por su arreglo y cuidado*. Sin embargo, por el contexto se ve que en Colombia alguien mono es aquel que es rubio.

El DRAE refleja que efectivamente es así, y solo en Colombia:

> [**mono, -a**](http://lema.rae.es/damer/srv/search?id=nqjyJN52Yx0A21dOfyt%7CsmLeeL2Wyx0AmwjE703%7CV7xhc39Onx0AWQS3Dvo).
>   1.  adj/sust. Co. Referido a persona, que tiene el pelo rubio.
>   2.  adj. Co. Referido al pelo, rubio.

La pregunta es: ¿por qué es así? Encontré [esta pregunta en Yahoo respuestas](https://espanol.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20120629134841AAJA23V) pero ofrece tantas posibles respuestas que no me acabo de quedar con ninguna.

Comment: Pues no he encontrado nada hasta ahora. La respuesta con más puntuación del enlace que colocas no me convence: 1) Es cierto que al sol le dicen algunos el "mono" pero es precisamente por el color "dorado" y eso nos deja en el comienzo. 2) La explicación de una muñeca de tela cosida que fue inspiración para Barbie me suena algo poco creíble. La otra respuesta que dice que viene de un nombre con significado "de origen noble" es quizá lo que podría tener algo de sentido... Pero no tengo idea.

Comment: Igualmente se podría preguntar por qué se llama "mono" a alguien de aspecto agradable, o por qué al síndrome de abstinencia se le llama "mono"... :-)

Comment: [En Reddit ofrecen otra hipótesis](https://www.reddit.com/r/Colombia/comments/7kp71w/por_qu%C3%A9_en_colombia_se_llama_mona_a_la_mujer_de/): _La cultura colombiana es muy sarcástica; nos gusta encontrar chiste en todo [burletera] . Entonces en situaciones cómo estás una persona rubia es lo opuesto a un mono= mico que es claramente opuesto de una persona rubia con facciones claras; ojos claros piel clara. Entonces lo decimos por molestar pero no para ofender._

Comment: Ya me extrañaba a mí que una pregunta así no la hubieras mandado al Reddit de Colombia. :-)

Comment: @Charlie es la típica pregunta que cuando redacto ya tengo dos pestañas abiertas: una con [spanish.se] y la otra con Reddit :P

Comment: La explicación de Reddit tendría sentido si usáramos la palabra "mono" para referirnos también al animal, pero esa palabra casi no se usa con ese sentido. Como allí se dice, lo que usamos es "mico". Si se quisiera usar el sarcasmo usaríamos la palabra "mico" en lugar de "mono", en mi opinión.

Comment: Estoy exactamente igual que @MauricioMartinez No me parece válida ninguna de las hipótesis hasta ahora planteadas y tampoco tengo idea de donde sale. El uso de "mono" para los rubios es tan antiguo y natural en Colombia que nunca me había preguntado por su origen.

Comment: Fíjate que se da lo mismo con el _fair hair_ del inglés, donde el rubio es el "pelo bonito". Tal vez "pelo mono" = "pelo bonito" ---> "mono" = "rubio".

Comment: A la familia de mi abuela de la provincia de Valladolid de España y nacida sobre 1915 les llamaban los monines y eran por lo rubio de su color de pelo

Comment: en Ecuador "mona" or "mono" se refiere a una persona de Guayaquil (:
ex: "*de donde eres?*"
"*soy mona!*"
(q vive ecuador carajo ;p )

Answer (score 4):

En "Semántica hispanoamericana" de Charles Emily Kany (1962) se sugiere que el significado "rubio" de la palabra "mono" en Colombia se debe al "*color de ciertos monos del país*". El [mono ardilla común](http://www.monkeyworlds.com/es/mono-ardilla/), por ejemplo, tiene el pelaje de las extremidades y el lomo amarillos. Y veo en [Diccionario de americanismos](http://lema.rae.es/damer/?key=mono) de la RAE que en Bolivia al mono tití se le dice *mono amarillo*. Me parece difícil confirmar esta hipótesis, pero esta foto de un mono ardilla es bastante elocuente:

[image: Saimiri sciureus - Mono ardilla común]

Comment: Los monos en españa/marruecos son tambien rubios: https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Macaca_sylvanus

Answer (score 1):

Mono también hace referencia a una figura: el mono de la pila, la mona del álbum. Más bien creo que deriva de una acepción étnica, en tanto que los españoles eran rubios y se decían monos (bellos).

Comment: Interesante... ¿tienes alguna referencia?